# AVRDude/USBTiny failing to initialize with ATMega2560 using AVR Pocket Programmer

Tags: arduino, atmega, avrdude

I have a brand new Atmega2560 sitting on a board that I made. I'm trying to use a Sparkfun AVR Pocket Programmer to program the board with USBTiny/AVRdude but when I input `avrdude -c usbtiny -p atmega2560 -v -v -v` into the CMD for avrdude, I'm getting an error as seen below

```
avrdude: programmer operation not supported

avrdude: Using SCK period of 10 usec
CMD: [ac 53 00 00] [00 00 00 00]
CMD: [ac 53 00 00] [00 00 00 00]
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1

Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
this check.
```

I checked connections and the board is fine. I was able to program it with a friends AVR Pocket Programmer without issue. For some reason, this one isn't working. I programmed another board I have without issue so I don't think it's the pocket programmer. I would use his again, but he's in another state.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up triple checking my connections and MOSI wasn't fully connected to the board. Strange.

Suggestions for those who run into this issue in the future:

1. Check connections. Double check connections. Triple check connections. Make sure the pad from the MCU is touching the pad of the board
2. Try slowing the speed of the read. ex: `avrdude -c usbtiny -p atmega2560 -B 250`
3. Make sure your avrdude is upto date - I'm currently using `avrdude version 6.0.1`
4. Make sure your drivers are up to date

From what I've read, with other peoples experiences, is that it is usually number 1 - the connections not being correct.

For others, if you changed your fuses and it stopped responding. You may have 'bricked' your MCU and need the programmer/debugger from AVR to unbrick it.